# CheckBox_Checked event

Tags: c#, silverlight, checkbox, counter

I eight check boxes in a Silverlight app, they are getting checked every time the windows that holds them is loaded, this keeps checking and un-checking the boxes without any user input.

Is there a way to and a counter for instance, to make sure the CheckBox_Checked event is not used every time the window is loaded?

Something like-

```
private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0
    if(counter == 1)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        //do something
    }
    counter1 = 1;
}
```

Comment: There is a reason for that, so it would be good if you find that reason. But if you want the workaround, make a private bool field LoadInProgress and set it to true. On the Window_Loaded event, set the bool to false. On your Checked event - if(LoadInProgress) return;

Comment: Define your counter as global variable outside checkbox1_checked subroutine.

Comment: this works for when you check a chekcbox, however what is the event when you uncheck a checkbox, as it its missing this input?

Comment: What about using the checkBox1_CheckedChanged Event Handler Instead?...

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic that sets the event for checked to the Silverlight equivalent of Form_Load.