# Managing `CheckBox_Checked` Event without an infinite loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox

I know this seems like an easy fix, but I am having trouble. I have a `CheckBox`, when checked, I remove the data source of a `DataGridView` on my `Windows Form` and remove the `ReadOnly` properties of a few `Textbox`.

I know the `CheckedChanged` event will send my code into an infinite loop, but I cannot figure out which event would handle this change without changing the `CheckedState` each time. I have tried using `Click`, `MouseClick`, and `CheckStateChanged` events with no luck.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub chkManual_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkManual.MouseClick

        If Not Me.chkManual.Checked Then
        Me.chkManual.Checked = False
        Me.cbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1

        Me.txtIssueDate.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtCasenum.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtCommnum.ReadOnly = True

        Exit Sub

   Else
        Me.dgDataEntry.DataSource = Nothing
        Me.cbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1

        Me.txtIssueDate.ReadOnly = False
        Me.txtCasenum.ReadOnly = False
        Me.txtCommnum.ReadOnly = False
        ClearForm()

        frmPDF.Hide()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End Sub
```

Properties of `CheckBox`: `AutoCheck` = `True`, `Checked` = `False`, and `CheckState` = `Unchecked`

I have looked into these already:

[CheckBox_Checked event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584387/checkbox-checked-event)

[Is there a simpler way to process check boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359462/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-process-check-boxes)

[CheckBox reverts to checked after being unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596907/checkbox-reverts-to-checked-after-being-unchecked)

[How to check if a checkboxes state has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898168/how-to-check-if-a-checkboxes-state-has-changed)

[How can I prevent an assignment statement to CheckBox.Checked from raising the CheckChanged event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613146/how-can-i-prevent-an-assignment-statement-to-checkbox-checked-from-raising-the-c)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?758455-CheckBox-code-got-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-can-not-unchecked-it

**EDIT**

It helps if your `ClearForm()` sub doesn't change the `CheckedState` of your `CheckBox` back to `False` every time. Thank you @Visual Vincent for pointing out the obvious. Nothing is wrong with the code, changed the `EventHandler` to `CheckedChanged`

Final code (so simple):

```
Private Sub chkManual_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkManual.CheckedChanged
    If Me.chkManual.Checked Then
        Me.dgDataEntry.DataSource = Nothing
        Me.cbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1

        Me.txtIssueDate.ReadOnly = False
        Me.txtCasenum.ReadOnly = False
        Me.txtCommnum.ReadOnly = False

        ClearForm()
        frmPDF.Hide()
    Else
        Me.cbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1

        Me.txtIssueDate.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtCasenum.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtCommnum.ReadOnly = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Removing the `Me.chkManual.Checked = False` line and putting the code in the CheckedChanged event should work if you're using a System.Windows.Forms CheckBox. --- Also, you don't need the `Exit Sub` line if you don't have any more code below the If-statement. :)

Comment: By the way, does the `ClearForm()` method by any chance change the state of your checkbox?

Comment: WOW! That's exactly what it was...the `ClearForm()` Sub changed the state of the `CheckBox`. I feel so silly, I knew I was missing something so simple. Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the CheckBox, when Checked, to Uncheck again automatically or not!?...seems like a weird interface.

At any rate, if you want something to occur when the Check state changes:

```
Private Sub chkManual_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkManual.CheckedChanged
    If chkManual.Checked Then
        Debug.Print("Checked")
        Me.dgDataEntry.DataSource = Nothing
        Me.cbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1

        Me.txtIssueDate.ReadOnly = False
        Me.txtCasenum.ReadOnly = False
        Me.txtCommnum.ReadOnly = False
        ClearForm()

        frmPDF.Hide()
    Else
        Debug.Print("UnChecked")
        Me.cbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1

        Me.txtIssueDate.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtCasenum.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtCommnum.ReadOnly = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You can uncheck the checkbox without an infinite loop like this:

```
Private Sub chkManual_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkManual.CheckedChanged
    Static counter As Integer
    If chkManual.Checked Then
        counter = counter + 1 ' just to show we're not in an infinite loop...
        Debug.Print("Checked " & counter) ' just to show we're not in an infinite loop...
        chkManual.Checked = False
    Else
        Debug.Print("UnChecked")
    End If
End Sub
```

Not sure why you'd want to do that...seems like that would basically be a "reset" button as it couldn't stay in a checked state...

Comment: The first block of code, as-is, never fires the `Check` = `True`, so none of the `Textbox` controls `ReadOnly` properties are changed.

Comment: ?...sure it does; I tested it.  If it's not working then you've got other issues/events in play, as further evidenced by your later comment of `ClearForm()` affecting your behavior...

Comment: yes you are correct. I will mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the code that changes the checkbox state? Ex:

```
Me.chkManual.Checked = False
```

The box will check or uncheck without your code having to do it, and the event will only throw once.

Comment: Doing so automatically unchecks the box, even without the `MouseClick` event firing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to remove event listener before handling checkbox checked state. Use try-finally block to ensure that checkbox event listener is always set back.

```
Try
RemoveHandler chkManual AddressOf chkManual_MouseClick
Me.chkManual.Checked = False
...
Finally
AddHandler chkManual AddressOf chkManual_MouseClick
End Try
```

Comment: I am intrigued by this method, but when I add these lines and try to uncheck the `CheckBox`, but the `Finally` condition adds the handler again regardless of the `CheckedState`. Any ideas?

Comment: You should add the handler always back to ensure the checkbox keeps working as normally.

Comment: I added it before `End Sub`, but that made no difference.